# Is it possible to distribute using Testflight and crashreport with crashlytics

Tags: ios, testflight

I am using testflight to distribute a beta of my app and sometimes having issues logging in to the websites.  I want to try crashlytics but i read that there some issues with using both at the same time.  Can i not include testflight SDK and still be able to distribute beta using it? Is that a normal practice or i should just stick to one?  What about using hockeyapp for both?

Also for people that use crashlytics do you ask the user first to allow sending crash reports.

PS if this question is not approriate for stackoverflow please let me know where with stackexchange

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use the testflight SDK to distribute with testflight, so remove that and use ccrashlytics.

You can ask them before they become the beta user, you dont need to ask each time.  If you put that code into production, then you should ask every time before sending.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will do that.  I just found out that Crashlytics supports user notification when the send a report.

Answer (score 11):

Wayne from Crashlytics here. Crashlytics is compatible and you shouldn't have any worries. For support you can contact at support.crashlytics.com.

Comment: Thanks!  I will do that next time i have a question about crashlytics.

Comment: @Wayne Chang, can we use Crashlytics for distributing IOS app to end user outside the app store? Is it possible without adding users UUID and distribute it using Crashlytics?